# Hit test for dynamic object

Tags: arcgis-engine

I am drawing a dynamic moving vehicle like this:

```
m_dynamicSymbolProperties.set_DynamicGlyph(esriDynamicSymbolType.esriDSymbolMarker, this.bluePoliceCarGlyph);
m_dynamicSymbolProperties.SetScale(esriDynamicSymbolType.esriDSymbolMarker, .3f, .3f);
currentUnitPosition = getNextPosition();
dynamicDisplay.DrawMarker(currentUnitPosition);
```

Does anyone know an easy way to do a hit test on my vehicle?  I am having trouble with this code example, http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/How_to_identify_objects_in_dynamic_display/0001000004s2000000/

---

One of the issues I have with the example is that ESRI states:

*ArcGIS versions 9.2 and later have the following three display systems that use OpenGL as their underlying drawing pipe—ArcGlobe/GlobeControl, ArcScene/SceneControl, and MapControl's dynamic display.*

So I am trying to get a hit test for a dynamic display object, but according to the tutorial, part 1 (link above), I have to use the OpenGL display system to give my dynamic display object a watermark in order for the hit test to work.  This makes no sense at all.

```
uint ID = Convert.ToUInt32(r[0]);
OpenGL.GL.glLoadName(ID);
```

---

Another issue I have is when this code is called

```
IArray dynamicHitArray = m_dynamicDisplay.Locate(x, y,
    esriDynamicSelectionMode.esriDSMLayers, this as IDynamicLayer);
```

Another event is fired off to DrawDynamicLayer and I will get a stackoverflow unless I do this

```
if(!someBool)
{
    someBool = true; 
    IArray dynamicHitArray = m_dynamicDisplay.Locate(x, y,
        esriDynamicSelectionMode.esriDSMLayers, this as IDynamicLayer);

  someBool = false; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I grabbed the OpenGL files from this sample: http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Sample_Dynamic_display_compass/0001000004nq000000/

Then in my DynamicLayer (CustomDynamicLayer) I do this:

```
public override void DrawDynamicLayer(esriDynamicDrawPhase DynamicDrawPhase, IDisplay iDisplay, IDynamicDisplay iDynamicDisplay) 
{

OpenGL.GL.glLoadName(id); //id is arbitrary
m_dynamicSymbolProperties.set_DynamicGlyph(esriDynamicSymbolType.esriDSymbolMarker, unitIcon);
m_dynamicSymbolProperties.SetScale(esriDynamicSymbolType.esriDSymbolMarker, .3f, .3f);
dynamicDisplay2.DrawMarker(position);
}
```

Then in my main app I have an event handler for AfterDynamicDraw

```
public void OnAfterDynamicDraw(esriDynamicMapDrawPhase dynamicMapDrawPhase, IDisplay Display, IDynamicDisplay dynamicDisplay) 
{

  IDynamicDisplay2 dynamicDisplay2 = dynamicDisplay as IDynamicDisplay2; 

  //test some x,y that i know i hit
  IArray thisArray = dynamicDisplay2.Locate(674, 249,   esriDynamicSelectionMode.esriDSMLayers, this.customDynamicLayer as IDynamicLayer);
}
```